# Ruby four-digit number, how to check it whether they are two the same numbers

Tags: ruby

How to check that there are at least two the same values on four-digit number or there aren't at least two the same values
for example 2432 - there are two 2, how to check it and then spit out an information that there are at least two or more the same numbers in this four-digit number?

```
puts "enter four-digit number: "
four_digit_num = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Comment: Is this homework? Are you allowed to convert to string? If so, you can use `gets.chomp.split.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:count).values.any? { |val| val > 1 }`

Comment: Yes, thank you for your involvement. I'll try it :)

Comment: @maxpleaner You probably meant #chars rather than #split.

Comment: @bubuq3 : If the user enters i.e. `010`, does this have two same-digits (the zero), or not (because the leading one does not count)? What is the expected outcome, if there are three identical digits, as in `555`?

Comment: @user1934428 Im newbie and I don't get it what you said. If there will be 2 or more indentical digit then it will tell us about them.

Comment: I'm not talking about programming, but about the problem itself you are going to solve, so it does not matter whether you are a newbie. If the user enters `010`, do you want to respond with "has two identical digits" (because you see two zeroes in the input), or do you want to respond with "does not have two identical digits" (because 010 is mathematically equal to 10 and this has only one copy of each digit).

Comment: Ok, I get it. That's interesting: 010 will show that there is two zeros 0

Comment: For fun you could use the following regular expression to test whether a four-character string contains two pairs of digits `d1` and `d2`, `d1 != d2`: `r = /(\d)(?=\d*\1)\d*(?!\1)(\d)\d*\2/`. Try it: `'1234'.match?(r) #=> false; '1232'.match?(r) #=> false; '1221'.match?(r) #=> true; '1111'.match?(r) #=> false`...

Comment: ... The regex reads, "match a digit saved to capture group 1, followed by the *positive lookahead* `(?=\d*\1)` that asserts the first digit matched is followed by zero or more digits followed by a digit equal to the contents of capture group 1, with the digit saved to capture group 1 followed by zero or more digits followed by the *negative lookahead* `(?!\1)` that asserts the following character is not equal to the content of capture group 1, followed by a digit saved to capture group 2, followed by zero or more digits followed by a digit equal to the contents of capture group 2.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, but regex is all Greek to me and I need to practice more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that as follows.

```
r = /(\d)\d*\1/
```

```
gets.match?(r)    # when gets #=> "1231\n"
  #=> true 
gets.match?(r)    # when gets #=> "1232\n"
  #=> true 
gets.match?(r)    # when gets #=> "1234\n"
  #=> false
```

We can write the regular expression in *free-spacing* mode to make it self-documenting.

```
r = /
    (\d)   # match a digit and save to capture group 1
    \d*    # match zero or more digits
    \1     # match the contents of capture group 1
    /x     # specify free-spacing regex definition mode
```

See [String#match?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-match-3F).

---

If you must begin with the integer

```
four_digit_num = gets.to_i
```

you could write

```
arr = four_digit_num.digits
arr.uniq.size < arr.size
```

or convert it to a string and apply the first method above:

```
four_digit_num.to_s.match?(r)
```

Comment: Thank you :) I'll struggle with it tomorrow.

Comment: r = /(\d)\d*\1/

puts "enter a four-digit number: "
num = gets.match?(r)

puts num.to_s
 it shows me an error: /6.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined method `match?' for "1231\n":String (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  match

Comment: Ok, I've got the newest version and it works: ruby 2.7.2p137

Comment: `String#match?` made its debut in v2.4, but you could instead write `!!(gets =~ r)`, `!!(gets.match)` or `!!(gets[r])`, all of which employ `String` methods that are as old as the hills. `!!` is an old trick to convert a *truthy* value (a logically `true` value, anything other than `nil` and `false`) to `true` and convert a *falsy* value (a logically false value, `nil` or `false`) to `false`. For example `!!"cat" => !(!"cat")) => !false => true`. Of course, a truthy or falsy value may suffice. For example,  you could write `puts "There are repeats" if gets =~ r`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have up to two pairs of duplicates, so that's probably a use case that needs to be handled. In any case, with Ruby 2.7.2 you might use a Hash to count occurrences of each digit in your String using [Hash#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) (via Enumerable) like so:

```
def report_duplicates_in(digits)
  dupes = digits.to_s.chars.tally.select { _2 > 1 }
  puts "dupliicate digits=>counts for #{digits}: #{dupes}" if dupes.any?
  [digits, dupes]
end

# test with some values
%w[1234 2432 2442].map do |four_digit_num|
  report_duplicates_in(four_digit_num)
end.to_h
```

This will print the following to standard output and return a Hash:

> ```
> dupliicate digits=>counts for 2432: {"2"=>2}
> dupliicate digits=>counts for 2442: {"2"=>2, "4"=>2}
> #=> {"1234"=>{}, "2432"=>{"2"=>2}, "2442"=>{"2"=>2, "4"=>2}}
> ```

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the suggestion to simplify with #tally. If anyone needs the longer chain-wreck for pre-2.7, they can grab it from the edit history.

Answer (score 0):

Test for unique digits:

```
four_digit_num = gets.to_i
digits = four_digit_num.digits # leading zeros will disappear
puts "2 or more same digits." if digits != digits.uniq
```